# virtual host and IP address mapping

Tags: nginx, iptables, virtualhost

I have a rackspace server running with nginx. I am a newbie to all the server stuff. Let me explain the situation here:

1. I have an IP address and I have two virtual host on my machine.
2. I don't have a domain and I don't want to buy any
3. I want to map it so I can access the website as xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/v_host1 and xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/v_host2

How can I do this the easy way? I am guessing I should change the nginx config of my site... but not sure which one to change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works, but have a look at this: [Mixed IP and Name Based Virtual Hosts with nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/195054/mixed-ip-and-name-based-virtual-hosts-with-nginx/195064#195064)

The nginx config file is usually `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Comment: I looked and there isn't any default in that folder

Comment: If the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder exists, then you can create a file with any file name in that folder and put your config rules there.

Answer (score 0):

First, **VirtualHost** is an Apache term. NGINX does not have Virtual hosts, it has **Server Blocks**

You will want to create a server block for each of your sites, each of them using the IP you wish to assign to the site.

Your configuration would look something like this:

```
server {
  listen          12.34.56.78:80;
  server_name     12.34.56.78;

  location / {
        return 410;  # Default root of site won't exist.
    }

  location /v_host1/ {
    index           index.html;
    root            /var/www/v_host1
  }

  location /v_host2/ {
    index           index.html;
    root            /var/www/v_host2
  }
}
```